# Render() Modal test Jest Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am not really how to test render() Modal. I am able to set up the props and test Render () " make sure it render with all the props" correctly " without any problems.
But when it comes to Render Modal - i might be missing something

Using ReactJS 15 - jest enzyme VSC

```
it(' Should render with all of the props ', () => {  
tree = renderer.create(<Component {...baseProps} />)
let treeJson = tree.toJSON()
expect(treeJson).toMatchSnapshot();
tree.unmount()
 });
```

I found this online but and try to test it but i believe there might be something missing. Any ideas?

```
it('renders correctly', () => {
const wrapper = mount( <Component modalOpen/> );
expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
// Passes
expect(wrapper.find('.outside')).toHaveLength(1);
// Construct new wrapper rooted at modal content
inside_els = document.getElementsByClassName("inside")[0]
inside_wrapper = new ReactWrapper(inside_els, true)

// Passes
expect(inside_wrapper.find('.inside')).toHaveLength(1);
```

Here is an example  of render() Modal

```
 render() {
   //console.log(this.props)
   return (
  <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen} style={modalStyle}>
    <div className='security-search-wrapper-modal'>
      <div className='fullmodal'> 
        <div className='fullmodal_title'>Batch Update</div>
        <div title="Close Window" className="add-custom-field-close" 
onClick={() => {this.closeModal()}}><FontAwesome name='xbutton' 
className='fa-times' /></div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research :  I was able to find this:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal/issues/563

Feel free to comment